# How access to field from second table in joint statement

Tags: api, c#

I try to join 2 tables in SOQL that I am using in C#. not sure how get the value from second table that is contact table.
This is my query:

```
 SOQL = "select Name,FirstName,LastName,BillingCity,Id, (Select ID, LastName,Title from Contacts) from Account";

        queryResult = SfdcBinding.query(SOQL);
        if (queryResult.size > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.size; i++)
            {

                Account acc = (Account)queryResult.records[i];
                string name = acc.Name;
                string FirstName = acc.FirstName;
                string LastName = acc.LastName;
                string city = acc.BillingCity;
                string Id = acc.Id;

            }
```

How access to ID, LastName,Title from contact table in C# code?

Comment: why would you use SOQL in C# :?.

Comment: Because I am using SalesForce API and it should be in SOQL.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**       *Note: this is exactly what sfdcfox said*

Since you are querying Contacts with Accounts, the Account will have the list of Contacts returned as a `Contact[]` called "Contacts".

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.size; i++){
    Account acc = (Account)queryResult.records[i];
    string name = acc.Name;
    string FirstName = acc.FirstName;
    string LastName = acc.LastName;
    string city = acc.BillingCity;
    string Id = acc.Id;

    Contact[] contacts = (Contact[])acc.Contacts;

    for(int j=0; i<contacts.length; j++){
        Contact con = contacts[j];
        string contactId = con.id;
        string contactLastName = con.LastName;
        string contactTitle = con.Title;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @amatorVitae for your reply. I am getting error on line: Contact[] contacts = (Contact[])acc.Contacts;         this is error I am getting: "Cannot convert type QuertResult to Contact[] "

Answer (score 1):

It is accessed much the same as you'd access it in Apex Code: the `acc` variable will have a member called `Contacts` which (should) be a `Contact[]` (or at worst, a `SObject[]`, which you can cast each member into a `Contact`). I'm not well-versed in .Net code, but based on what I do know about the language and WSDL in general, this should be about right.

Comment: I am getting error on line: Contact[] contacts = (Contact[])acc.Contacts; this is error I am getting: "Cannot convert type QuertResult to Contact[] "                         Do you know how I can get the fields from second table?

Answer (score 0):

acc.Contacts is a nested QueryResult, so you like you're accessing the records property of your top level query result, you do the same on the nested one, e.g.

```
Contact[] contacts = (Contact[])acc.Contacts.records
```

Also, queryResult.size is the size of the entire result, which may be significantly larger than the current chunk of results you have, so your outer loop based on `queryResult.size` should be changed to be based on the `queryResult.records.length` instead.

Comment: I get this error now on this line you added:   Unable to cast object of type 'sObject[]' to type 'Contact[]'.

Comment: probably you have a class called Contact that is conflicting with the generated one.